# Weapons will not equip after arrival to the South Island

Tags: far-cry-3

On the max difficulty, I went to the South Island. After I jumped from the plane, I died.  When I jumped again and landed safely, my weapons would not engage. Also, the second time the pirates were not on the beach.

So now I am running around the island with no weapons. Is there something I can do to continue and engage my weapons?

I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: Have you tried reloading it ?

Comment: Try turning it off and then back on again

Answer (score 1):

Try to reload a older save or just continue your mission and go to sam in the village. Maybe you had to drop your weapons, but you don't need them right now.